# Node.js server will not start but seems to connect to DB

Tags: node.js

I have a node application that is not working though did work about 2 hours ago (no code changes). Also no changes to the server, I only ran another node application on the same port but that process has been killed.

Command to start node `node server`

server.js

```
var app = require('./server/index');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

app.js (stripped down)

```
const   express = require("express"),
        mongoose = require("mongoose"),
        app = express();

mongoose.connect(config.db, {autoReconnect: true}, (err) => {
   if (!err) console.log('MongoDB has connected successfully.');
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
  console.error('MongoDB Connection Error. Make sure MongoDB is running.');
});

var authRoutes = require('./routes/auth.js');
authRoutes(app, passport);


module.exports = app;
```

Output when starting node process

```
(node:4341) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
(node:4341) DeprecationWarning: collection.ensureIndex is deprecated. Use createIndexes instead.
MongoDB has connected successfully.
```

Comment: mongo only show warnings, this is not problem, but why having 2 port2 used for Node.JS: `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);`, and `var server = app.listen(8080...`

Comment: You can't run 2 processes on the same port, if you want to run 2 different processes for a node app, please change port for the second with `process.env.PORT` (environment variable $PORT), but first you should fix the `server = app/.listen(port, ...)`, not use hard code `8080`

Comment: @huynhsamha I have 0 processes running... Thought that was clear...

Comment: What OS you are using? Linux, Windows or OSX?

Comment: If you are using Linux, please try `sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:8080)` to kill process `8080` running on OS, after that please sure change `app.listen(8080)` to `app.listen(port)` and kill the process running on port `port` (maybe it is `3000` if `PORT` not be set in environment)

Comment: @huynhsamha The reason I have it as `process.env.port || 3000` is because that is what I wanted it to be but I put `8080` in manually because that is what cloud9 prefers you run on. Also your command will not work since no processes are running on port 8080. As I said,0 (ZERO) processes are running on the port I am trying to run on. I am using Cloud9 so linux.

Comment: Also Cloud9 sets the process.env.port variable to 8080 by default and changing ports explicitly to 8081 or 8082 which are the other supported ports does not do anything. Something is either wrong with my code or something is wrong with the OS. Considering I just cloned my repo to a clean cloud9 instance and it failed.

Comment: You can't set port for app which port is different with port when `app.listen`, that will be not working. Please try one port (as your hope, that should be `8080`) when set port and listen. Thanks!

Comment: @huynhsamha As I figured my port was correct and nothing Linux related was the issue. Turns out it was my command, see my answer for my resolution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved it, seems that using `node server` was going directly into my server directory and running `app.js` file note the `server.js` file I wanted it to. Instead I had to run `node server.js`